# Keras doesn't make good predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, prediction

Two months ago I started working with keras in order to obtain a pump pattern for using it in other software.

I don't know the reason(s) why the patterns I obtain have nothing to do with the real ones. I have tried by establishing few features (inputs) in the dataset, and also with more inputs, but there is no way it works. 
The results seem like this:

[image: Bad results]

Where:

- Blue: dataset (real data I'm trying to "aproximate")
- Orange: prediction

The dataset is a Time Series

[here](https://mega.nz/#!SBtRUZIT!4R2Po4g0EOqYUPcojizsT-z7pICu4Zn--B6f0AYMk50)is the csv file with the dataset

Here is the code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.regularizers import l2, activity_l2


def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0:4] 
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 4]) 
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)



# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed=7
numpy.random.seed(seed)


# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('datos_horarios.csv', engine='python') 
dataset = dataframe.values


# normalizar el dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

#split data into train data and test data
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67) 
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

# reshape to X=t y Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)  
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape inputs to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], look_back, 4))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], look_back, 4))
# create and adjust LSTM network

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.3, input_shape=(look_back,4))) 
model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=(look_back,4), W_regularizer=l2(0.001))) 
model.add(Dense(10)) 
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam' ,momentum=0.99)
history= model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=250, batch_size=32)


# Plot
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend(['training', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
print(trainPredict)

numero_inputs=4
inp=numero_inputs-1
# Get something which has as many features as dataset
trainPredict_extended = numpy.zeros((len(trainPredict),numero_inputs+1))
# Put the predictions there
trainPredict_extended[:,inp+1] = trainPredict[:,0]
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict_extended)[:,inp+1]

# Get something which has as many features as dataset
testPredict_extended = numpy.zeros((len(testPredict),numero_inputs+1))
# Put the predictions there
testPredict_extended[:,inp+1] = testPredict[:,0]
# Inverse transform it and select the 3rd column.
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict_extended)[:,inp+1]

trainY_extended = numpy.zeros((len(trainY),numero_inputs+1))
trainY_extended[:,inp+1]=trainY
trainY=scaler.inverse_transform(trainY_extended)[:,inp+1]

testY_extended = numpy.zeros((len(testY),numero_inputs+1))
testY_extended[:,inp+1]=testY
testY=scaler.inverse_transform(testY_extended)[:,inp+1]
# Calcular error medio cuadratico
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY, trainPredict))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY, testPredict))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
# add train predictions to the plot

trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, 0] = trainPredict

# add test predictions to the plot
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, 0] = testPredict

# Plot real data and training and test predictions
serie,=plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset)[:,numero_inputs])  #invierto muestras en formato (0,1) a valores reales y los ploteo
entrenamiento,=plt.plot(trainPredictPlot[:,0],linestyle='--')  #ploteo las predicciones de entrenamiento
prediccion_test,=plt.plot(testPredictPlot[:,0],linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel(' (m3)')
plt.xlabel('h')
plt.legend([serie,entrenamiento,prediccion_test],['Time series','Training','Prediction'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Any ideas about how I can fix this problem? Or, at least, what the problem is?

INPUTS BY COLUMN:

1. Time of the day (each half an hour), converted to decimal.
2. Day of the week (1-Monday...7-sunday)
3. Month of the year (1-12)
4. Day of the month (1-31)

OUTPUT:

5. Pumped water (m3)

**EDIT**
Using the @a_guest 's code, and changing some parameters, such as the number of epochs or the `history` value, the results are really nice:

[image: Reference vs prediction]
[image: Relative deviation]

Comment: A few questions: Are you trying to predict future values of the time series based on the old ones? What does your data exactly represent ("pump pattern")? Is your data expected to be very noisy? Also take a look at [this article](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) (it's a bit lengthy but informative). And if you have some knowledge about what to expect as values you might be better off using a simple fit!

Comment: The target is to obtain a pattern of a water pump (when it should me conected and disconected during the day). The Time Series represents the pumped water (m3) spaced half an hour. In fact, I saw that article and my code is based in that website (I hace read all the articles). Unfortunately, I'm doing a thesis and it is compulsory to use ANN. In going to edit the post to show what inputs are.

Comment: Your `LSTM` output has 6 neurons and it comes to `Dense` which has `10`. Moreover - you have only six units to analyse history. I would first try to increase a number of nodes in `LSTM` layer to - let's say `40`.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand so well which is the number of neurons per layer. I have changed the number of nodes to 40 but the results look almost the same (but the training seems to improve and the MSE also improves!).Thank you, this is a progress

Comment: @Jvr You are using a `look_back` value of `1`, which means you are trying to predict a value based only on the previous value (?). You should probably increase the number of data points taken into account. Also note that your data probably exhibits different ["seasonalities"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality) at different frequencies (daily cycle (more water during the day) + year cycle (more water during summer)). To learn a year cycle you need much more data. IMO for a prediction you should cover at least the last 48 hours (so the network saw that pattern already at least once).

Comment: Yes, look_back is 1 because of my last "experiment" changing parameters. But previously I haved tried with other numbers. Now I will try again. Yes, seasonality is the main problem I had detected. Obviously, during the summer, for example, the pumped water increases a lot, and in fact, the target of the thesis is to determine a pattern for weekends in each seasons and a pattern for week days in each season, but I don't know how at all. The problem is that I just can get the data of today, tomorrow I will be able to get the data for tomorrow...but I don't have a historical series.

Comment: @a_guest I have set a look_back=96 (2 days) and I obtain the same MSE score but in 15 minutes of training instead of some seconds. I don't know how to fix this problem having no much more data to use as time series. I don't know if fixing the seasonality it will work...

Comment: Well actually looking at your plot, the predictions are not too bad; the network seems to be able to extract some features from your data, specifically a rise during the day and then a sharp fall at the end of the day. This is also roughly what the blue curve shows (machines' judgments tend to be less biased here). If you want your network to also learn the oscillations which correspond to higher frequencies it might help to use more neurons or add additional layers to the network. But beware of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) which doesn't learn the patterns anymore.

Comment: @a_guest That's what I have done; add more neurons and additional layers but it doesn't seem to improve :(

Comment: Although this would limit the application of your code, what happens if you add the previous y value (y_{t-1}) to the input x (at time x_{t})?

Comment: @Tomer Levinboim  I think your suggestion is implemented with the function create_dataset() and setting look_back as the number of previous steps.

Comment: Thanks... I made a quick comment based on the INPUTS BY COLUMN part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer but I share the code here with which I obtained the following results:

[image: Predictions]

[image: Relative deviation]

Note that the network parameters are chosen arbitrarily, i.e. not optimized. That is you can most likely get better results by varying those parameters. Also varying the value of `history` (or `look_back` in your case) probably has a significant effect on the quality of predictions.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(12)

history = 96


def generate_data():
    data = numpy.loadtxt('datos_horarios.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
    # Normalize data.
    data[:, -1] /= numpy.max(data[:, -1])
    train_test_data = []
    for i in xrange(data.shape[0] - history - 1):
        # Include the reference value here, will be extracted later.
        train_test_data.append(data[i:i+history+1, -1].flatten())
    return numpy.array(train_test_data)

train_test_data = generate_data()
# Shuffle data set in order to randomly select training and test data.
numpy.random.shuffle(train_test_data)

n_samples = train_test_data.shape[0]
n_train_samples = int(0.8 * n_samples)

train_data = train_test_data[:n_train_samples, :-1]
train_data_reference = train_test_data[:n_train_samples, -1][:, None]

test_data = train_test_data[n_train_samples:, :-1]
test_data_reference = train_test_data[n_train_samples:, -1]

print 'Tranining data: ', train_data
print 'Reference values: ', train_data_reference


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(history, input_dim=history, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(history/2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(history/4, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(history/8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(history/16, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(train_data, train_data_reference, shuffle=True, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=10)

# Use the complete data set to see the network performance.
# Regenerate data set because it was shuffled before.
train_test_data = generate_data()
test_data_predicted = model.predict(train_test_data[:, :-1]).flatten()
test_data_reference = train_test_data[:, -1]

relative_deviation = test_data_predicted/test_data_reference - 1.0
print 'Relative deviation: ', relative_deviation

plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(len(test_data_reference)), test_data_reference, 'b-', label='reference')
plt.plot(range(len(test_data_predicted)), test_data_predicted, 'r--', label='predicted')
plt.xlabel('test case #')
plt.ylabel('predictions')
plt.title('Reference values vs predicted values')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(len(test_data_predicted)), relative_deviation, 'bx', label='relative deviation')
plt.xlabel('test case #')
plt.ylabel('relative deviation')
plt.title('Relative deviation of predicted values (predicted / reference - 1)')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: This answer is simply awesome! You've helped me a lot. And I understand your code really well. As you say,I will change some parameters of the model architecture and if I get good results I will update the post. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jvr Glad to hear that. When I look at the plot from your edit I get the feeling that your network might have [overfitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the data (i.e. it learned the data "by heart"). Without doubt it's following the original curve very well however that also means that it doesn't reflect the underlying patterns so well anymore (it contains all the micro-fluctuations, noise). You should also verify the performance using test data which is _distinct_ from the training data. Also splitting the training and test data with regard to time would be reasonable.

Comment: Yes, is overfitted. What I have done to know it is to make the cross validation and now I am trying to set the correct parameters in order to obtain a correct pattern...